# Is it possible to query total CPU load on system that is hosting SQL Server 2014+ Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, cpu

I can get the available memory by querying the `[master].[sys].[dm_os_sys_memory]` view, but I haven't found anything similar for getting info about the CPU load.

I only find info about querying CPU load by the SQL server itself which is not my primary concern, I need the full load on the system.
I've looked through the system views but I can't find anything or at least don't understand if I've found it...

The reason I want to get this via T-SQL is that we already have a monitoring application that is querying all our systems for other info and it would be nice to be able to expand that instead of settings up something completely new.

Currently the systems of interest are running 2014 and 2017 express but it will probably include 2019/2022 express soon enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an Agent job in Powershell that runs every say 10 seconds and captures this information

```sql
CREATE TABLE CounterLog (id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, Counter decimal(18,9));
INSERT CounterLog (id) VALUES ('CPU');

EXEC msdb.sys.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'Get Counters';

EXEC msdb.sys.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Get Counters', 
    @step_name = N'Get CPU Load',
    @subsystem = N'PowerShell',  
    @command = N'
$load = (Get-Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples[0].CookedValue;

Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "." -Database "YourDb" -Query "
UPDATE CounterLog
SET Counter = ${$load}
WHERE id = ''CPU'';"
',   
    @on_success_action = 3;

EXEC msdb.sys.sp_add_jobschedule
    @job_name = N'Get Counters',
    @freq_type = 4,
    @freq_interval = 1, 
    @freq_subday_type = 2, 
    @freq_subday_interval = 10;
```

Comment: If I understand the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017) correctly SQL Server Agent isn't supported on Express versions?

Comment: Then create it as a Windows Scheduled Task

Comment: yeez sometimes I think my brain hasn't come back from vacation yet... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve that using [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to run one of the commands from this other [Q and A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097067/get-cpu-usage-from-windows-command-prompt/9097205#9097205):

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'wmic cpu get loadpercentage';
```

Just be sure to read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) of that procedure documentation since using it has security implications.

Comment: That would work but xp_cmdshell is a no go for security reasons unfortunately. But an upvote since you actually gave me a way to do it :) EDIT: seems like I have to low rep to actually give you an upvote :(